# Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound error when using Carrierwave to upload to Rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave, rackspace, fog

Everyone: I already searched the error before I posted this to Stackoverflow, so no need to point me to this: groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/carrierwave/ It's not the same problem.

I'm using Carrierwave so users can upload files to my Rackspace container. But when I Submit from my site (on my local machine, still in test mode), I get a **Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound** app/controllers/authors_controller.rb:8:in `update' error. My Rackspace container is called kontainer.ofstuff. Here's my code:

pic_uploader.rb:

```
class PicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

model author.rb

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :stuff, :profilepic

  mount_uploader :pic, PicUploader

  def dostuff
  end
end
```

carrierwave.rb is in the config/initializers directory

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider           => 'Rackspace',
    :rackspace_username => 'myusername',
    :rackspace_api_key  => '98765asecretnumber3'
  })
  config.fog_directory = 'kontainer.ofstuff'
  config.fog_host = 'https://34567secretnumberiiiii.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com'
end
```

controller authors_controller.rb

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    @booklist = Book.where(:author_id => @author.id)
#line 7
    if @author.update_attributes(params[:author])
      sign_in @author
      redirect_to @author
    else
      render 'profileinfo'
    end
  end
end
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<%= f.file_field :pic %>
<%= f.submit "Save Author Info" %>
```

When I had this code 'uploading'/storing to a file, this worked fine. Perhaps f.submit does not work with Carrierwave? If not...where do I find the correct code for submitting?

Any ideas what the trouble is?

Comment: I've never used Rackspace, but are you giving the correct container name ? You might have the same error as https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/carrierwave/PV7n6RZ1DiU

Comment: Already saw that topic and I mentioned my container name above. So, no, that's not the issue I am having. I even tried making a new container, using new URL, etc. and still the same problem. And since containers don't recognize directories (only objects), I tried messing with taking directory names out of       def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end                with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of had the same problem, but for me it turned out that I needed to make the container multiple times with the same name but for all the regions. I have no idea why it worked after that, but I guess that's something to try?

**Update 11-7-2012**

So Carrierwave had some updates since my answer. I was able to get a more stable upload through some trial and error. Here's what I did:

1. Updated carrierwave gem to 0.7.0
2. Logged into Rackspace and deleted containers for all the regions.
3. Added one single container. It doesn't matter which region, whichever is more applicable to you.
4. Made the container public (Enable CDN)
5. Copied the Public HTTP CDN link for the container
6. Updated my /config/initalizers/carrierwave.rb file:

   ```
   CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.fog_credentials = {
       :provider           => 'Rackspace',
       :rackspace_username => '[Your Rackspace Username]',
       :rackspace_api_key  => '[Your Rackspace API key]'
     }
     config.fog_directory = '[The name of the container you created]'

     if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
       config.asset_host = '[The Public HTTP CDN url for the container]'
     end
   end
   ```

As a note: I configured my uploader to use storage:fog when the environment is production or staging. Otherwise I use the default local file system.

The main thing to note is that carrierwave changed the config 'fog_host' to 'asset_host.'

Comment: Jay, was that with Rackspace or AWS? I tried uploading to AWS instead (with a whole different set of upload errors) and the region can be specified.

Comment: Rackspace, but since my answer I updated carrierwave. They had an update since then. The settings are different now. I was able to get it more stable as well. I'll update my answer a bit with my new settings and what I did.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I moved on to AWS, but your suggestion to update the Carrierwave gem solved the issue!

Comment: No prob, Brad. I've actually moved to AWS as well. Much less headache since then. Can you accept the answer all the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error.
Solved by adding this to uploaded code:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ....

  def remove!
    begin
      super
    rescue Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: While this resolves the issue, it doesn't address the symptoms. Good enough for now, but wonder WTF is actually going on.

Comment: I had a very similar issue and this did work. In my case it seemed that the old file was being deleted before the record could update which would cause carrierwave to bug out. Still not 100% sure of the cause, but this does fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: I was having this same problem after migrating from AWS to Rackspace.  The error was being thrown because part of updating the file is deleting the old file. In my case, the old file was on S3, not on Rackspace, so carrierwave got upset.

Comment: Pretty much this: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Silently-ignore-missing-files-on-destroy-or-overwrite

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be a case of Wait A Few Months & install updated gem. The problem pretty much went away. I also got rid of Rackspace & went to Amazon S3, although I had tried S3 earlier with the same issues. I'm crediting the solution to the updated Carrierwave gem.